# Cannot view angular app project in nginx via localhost

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, dockerfile

I did search on how to dockerized an angular app with Nginx.
However it doesn't show in my http://localhost:8080/ or http://locahost:8000

Below are my files: (Docker File)

```
FROM node:10.16.1-alpine as build-stage
COPY . /usr/angular
WORKDIR /usr/angular
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

#Deploy to NGINX
FROM nginx:1.16.0-alpine as deployment-stage
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
COPY --from=build-stage /usr/angular/dist/ldap-web-app/*  /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Then I run commands in my bash.

1. `docker build -t ldap-web-app .`
2. docker run -it -p 80:80 --name ldap-web-app ldap-web-app

When I open my browser, "page cannot be displayed".
Did I miss something? Please help. Thanks you.

Comment: you're exposing port 80. Why are you trying to access it on 8080 or 8000? have a
look at the output of ´netstat -tunpl´ to check which ports are open. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are exposing container's port `80` to docker host but you are trying to access it at ports `8080` or `8000`.

Assuming that everything has been successfully setup regarding `nginx`,

try one of the following commands depending on which port you wish angular app to be available on your docker host:

Available at http://locahost:8080

```
docker run -it -p 8080:80 --name ldap-web-app ldap-web-app
```

Available at http://locahost:8000

```
docker run -it -p 8000:80 --name ldap-web-app ldap-web-app
```

Available at http://locahost

```
docker run -it -p 80:80 --name ldap-web-app ldap-web-app
```

The port mapping should be declared like this:

```
-p CONTAINER:HOST
```

I would reccommend  you reading [official docs](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/).

Answer (score 0):

You expose port 80 of the container to the outside thus need to connect there. *Not to 8080 or 8000*

"docker run -it **-p 80:80** --name ldap-web-app ldap-web-app"

Check the documentation - https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#published-ports

```
-p 8080:80  - Map TCP port 80 in the container to port 8080 on the Docker host.
```